# Validation Error in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I had an entity :

```
public class Book
{
public int BookID{get; set;}
public string BookName{get; set;}
public int Price {get; set;}
}
```

I scaffolded and created Controller and Views automatically. Then I changed my entity to this :

```
public class Book
{
public int BookID{get; set;}
public string BookName{get; set;}
public double Price {get; set;}
}
```

I copied my project, then deleted controller and views, recreated them automatically. Then copied the content of controller and views from the old one. Now when I enter 18.75 I get "The value '18.75' is not valid for Price." error. How can I fix this situation? Thanks.

Comment: Enter "18,75", seems problem in current culture and decimal separator

Comment: You should use `decimal` for currency, not `double`.

Comment: @IgorSemin When I enter "18.75", I get : "The field Price must be a number." I changed Price to decimal btw.

Comment: it's no matter, 18.75 correct value for decimal and double, need check decimal separator in regional setting for server

Comment: Can you please show us your regional settings (Control Center -> Regional Settings)

Comment: @StephenReindl My regional Settings are Turkey.

Comment: AFAIK Turkey is using the comma as the decimal separator. Either use a comma, switch to English or use my answer below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyhow. I' avoiding this in the meantime by handling decimal input (mostly) independent on regional settings by having my own decimal handler:

1. in Startup/FilterConfig.cs:

   ```
   ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(decimal), new DecimalModelBinder());
   ```
2. A new class DecimalModelBinder:

   ```
   public class DecimalModelBinder : IModelBinder
   {
     public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
     {
       ValueProviderResult valueResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider
           .GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
       ModelState modelState = new ModelState { Value = valueResult };
       object actualValue = null;
       try
       {
           actualValue = GeneralHelper.ToDecimal(valueResult.AttemptedValue);
       }
       catch (FormatException e)
       {
           modelState.Errors.Add(e);
       }

       bindingContext.ModelState.Add(bindingContext.ModelName, modelState);
       return actualValue;
     }
   }
   ```

   The function `GeneralHelper.ToDecimal()` is based on the following blog entry: https://sreindl.wordpress.com/2013/10/26/i18n-parsing-decimal-values/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. A dummy question : I should place DecimalModelBinder class inside App_Start, right? And should I do anything  else in Controller or Views? Thank you.

Comment: I usually create a folder "Filters" (if not automatically created by Visual Studio) and place those filter classes there (I have a couple of them especially for table and regional number / date handling...)

Answer (score 1):

If the culture on your server handles decimal numbers with a comma, you also need to tell jQuery validation that it should be using comma's as decimal separators. You can take a look at [this blog-post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GlobalizationInternationalizationAndLocalizationInASPNETMVC3JavaScriptAndJQueryPart1.aspx) (a bit old but the stuff still works) for a general approach on handling the culture. The code here does the magic:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Ask ASP.NET what culture we prefer, because we stuck it in a meta tag
    var data = $("meta[name='accept-language']").attr("content")
    //Tell jQuery to figure it out also on the client side.
    $.global.preferCulture(data);

    //Tell the validator, for example,
    // that we want numbers parsed a certain way!
    $.validator.methods.number = function (value, element) {
        if ($.global.parseFloat(value)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Note that the link to the jQuery globalization plugin is dead. [It has been moved](https://github.com/jquery/globalize).

Basically you have to override the default number validation. I know that sucks but I yet have to find an approach as clean as this one.